# Internet connection periodically fails

Tags: internet, system-settings

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 desktop edition in my new computer . I have a problem with the  internet connection (Ethernet). Actually, my internet works for 20 seconds and it stops for 40 to 60 seconds. This cycle repeats and makes me difficult to work.

I tried editing the `/etc/reolv.conf` from

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1   
nameserver 8.8.8.8   
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

But the problem is not solved.

**Here is the `ifconfig` output  (I use eth0)**

```
eth0:     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:79:59:39:ae:80  
          inet addr:115.145.183.44  Bcast:115.145.183.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f279:59ff:fe39:ae80/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:195975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32299713 (32.2 MB)  TX bytes:2260481 (2.2 MB)
          Memory:fb300000-fb37ffff 

eth1:       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:79:59:39:ae:7f  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb700000-fb720000 

lo:         Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:350955 (350.9 KB)  TX bytes:350955 (350.9 KB)
```

**Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`**

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 05
       serial: f0:79:59:39:ae:7f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:97 memory:fb700000-fb71ffff memory:fb739000-fb739fff ioport:f020(size=32)




  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0f:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: f0:79:59:39:ae:80
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.2.13-k duplex=full firmware=3.25, 0x800005cf ip=115.145.183.44 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:fb300000-fb37ffff ioport:c000(size=32) memory:fb380000-fb383fff
```

Comment: have you tried allowing network-manager to set all this stuff for you?

Comment: I kind of used online commands to set the internet. I do not remember exactly. Since I followed everyone's instruction. That is my mistake. Please help me if you know some way. I would like to start from the scratch..

Comment: is network-manager installed? run `dpkg -l | grep network-manager` if not sure

Comment: I got the following output:  ii  network-manager                                   0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7  amd64  network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)ii  network-manager-gnome                                 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.3    amd64        network management framework (GNOME frontend)
ii  network-manager-pptp                                  0.9.8.2-1ubuntu2       amd64        network management framework (PPTP plugin core) ii  network-manager-pptp-gnome  0.9.8.2-1ubuntu2     amd64        network management framework (PPTP plugin GNOME GUI)

Comment: Does it help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following commands in an open terminal.

First, run the following command to zero out the resolv.conf file:

```
echo "# Generated by NetworkManager" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then, restart network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

You may need to click on the network-manager icon on your panel where you may then need to select the network from the dropdown menu or try unplugging and plugging the ethernet cable back in if you need to. If the issue is fixed, proceed no further. If not fixed, you may need to clear out your existing network configurations by running the following commands:

First, make a file to backup the existing cofigurations and then move the files there instead:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/NetworkManager/backupconnections
sudo mv /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* /etc/NetworkManager/backupconnections/
```

Now, restart network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

You may need to unplug and plug back in the ethernet cable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22389/discussion-on-answer-by-mchid-internet-connection-periodically-fails).